# Add gradient to select box w/ CSS3 in chrome?

Tags: css, gradient

I'm try to render a gradient background on some form elements. While it works fine for text and text areas, the same does not seem to work for selects in Chrome/Safari (though it does work on FF3) . Is there a way to accomplish this?

CSS code:

```
        .prettyform input, .prettyform textarea, .prettyform select {
            padding: 9px;
            border: 1px solid #E2E3E5;
            outline: 0;
            width: 400px;
            box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
            -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #E2E3E5), to(#FFFFFF));  
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #E2E3E5 1px, #FFFFFF 25px);
        }
```

HTML Markup:

```
    <form class='prettyform'>
        <p>
        <label>Text Input</label> <br>
        <input type='text' name='test1'>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label>Select Input</label> <br>
        <select name='test2'>
            <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
            <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
            <option value='3'>Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

[Live Demo](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5821809/styledemo.html)

Another thing I noticed is that even though they are both set to width: 400px, the select is noticeably shorter in both Chrome & Firefox. Why is this?

Comment: Weird. Your demo shows a gradient background in my chrome (but it shows a ugly border too...). In firefox 4, your select is shown with 400px with web dev toolbar, your input is 418px (since it got 9px padding from both side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im not entirely sure if you can style selects that much in any browser. They have always been a pain for css.

In ie, options wont expand to the width of the text, in firefox, they are shorter because of the dropdown icon etc. Its just a pain to use css for them. If you must have a styled select box, you can look at jquery UI as i believe they have some stylable select boxes

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do it in Chrome with background images, see http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/480-custom_forms.html for an example.  My biggest problem so far is finding a version that also works for Firefox, but if that's not a requirement for you, by all means check that site out and make use of the background image method.

Answer (score 0):

check my example and see how you can set gradient background for select on chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/DCjYA/361/

Answer (score 0):

For the record, mcmwhfy's answer above does not solve the issue with pure CSS, but is the only solution for SELECTs in Chrome.

The following will style input/textarea/select in every browser where possible, except for SELECTs in Chrome. But unfortunately, images are the only way to do it in Chrome right now.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f4f8ff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE8/9 */
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #F4F8FF 100%); /* IE10+ */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(102,204,255,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 20, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #f4f8ff), to(#FFFFFF));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #f4f8ff 1px, #FFFFFF 25px);
```