# Gradient style for <select> tag?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a form where the background of the input fields are styled with a gradient background. It succeds for all `<input>` tags, but not for the `<select>` tag. Can this be done? Am I doing something wrong?

The CSS I'm using:

```
form#contact input[type="text"], input[type="url"], 
input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], textarea, select {
    margin: 3px 0 0 0;
    padding: 6px; 
    width: 260px; 
    font-family: arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 15, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #f4f4f4), to(#FFFFFF));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #f4f4f4 1px, #FFFFFF 15px);
}
```

See the image below.

[image: See the image below]

Comment: in what browser? In firefox 5 looks ok

Comment: Tested in Chrome 15, looks OK here too.

Comment: I´m using Chrome 15.0.849.0 dev-m, and that´s where the above screenshot is from.

Comment: I would very honestly just use a background image for form controls.

Comment: Whilst flagged as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831957/add-gradient-to-select-box-w-css3-in-chrome, a year is a long time in browser timescales so unless anyone vehemently disagrees I'll keep this open. Also there's a much better discourse here than before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Styling `<select>` is difficult since browsers try and render the control to match the OS. You could add `-webkit-appearance: none;` to  enable the gradient but that will also remove the *arrow*.

See [Add gradient to select box w/ CSS3 in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831957/add-gradient-to-select-box-w-css3-in-chrome) and [Background Image for Select (dropdown) does not work in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226666/background-image-for-select-dropdown-does-not-work-in-chrome/5972981#5972981)

**Or** if you can use jQuery or Prototype, I highly recommend the excellent [Chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) in which the `<select>` is replaced by a dropdown that can be styled.

**Edit:** I have to add the styling form elements is sometimes frowned upon. Eric Meyer's [article on the subject](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/15/formal-weirdness/) is good background reading.

Comment: Thanks for providing several options and some good background info! I'll look into the JS plugins!

Answer (score 2):

You may have a problem with this due to the operating system and Internet Browser you are using.

One easy way of getting round this is by using a JQuery library called Uniform. It allows you to style form elements how you want and is cross-browser compatible.

You can find more information on this here: http://uniformjs.com/.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Good tip, I´ll take a look at this one aswell!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to debug that in firebug?

How about making the backgrounds important?

```
form#contact input[type="text"], input[type="url"], 

    input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], textarea, select {
        margin: 3px 0 0 0;
        padding: 6px; 
        width: 260px; 
        font-family: arial, sans-serif; 
        font-size: 12px; 
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 15, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #f4f4f4), to(#FFFFFF)) !important;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #f4f4f4 1px, #FFFFFF 15px) !important;
    }
```

Comment: Like Sotoris mentioned above, it works in FF5. Didn´t check that before posting..... however, I´m having issues with Chrome, and !important isn´t helping unfortunatly.